# How can I run Python scripts on a button click in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know how to run *.py* file on clicking a button in React.

All I want is to fetch the data created by the *.py* file using Flask on clicking a button in React application. I set up a link on that button which will redirect to another webpage on which I want to display that fetched data.

The React app and the *.py* file are on the same machine. How
can I do this?

My *app.js* file in the React app runs on "http://localhost:3000".

```
const onClickHandler = () => {
  // Fetching the data from the server localhost:5000/page_name
  const url = "http://localhost:5000/data";
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    try {
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      setName(data.name);
      setPassword(data.password);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return(
    <div>
    <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Click me</button>
        {name}
    {password}
    </div>
  );
```

My .py file runs on "http://localhost:5000/my_link"

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_link():
  print("I got Clicked")
  return {'name': "geek", "password": "This is PWD"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: you have to have the url as `http://localhost:5000/data` so it matches the route and invokes the function `my_link`

Comment: @KcH . Yeah thats my mistake its a typo . Right now i have to manually run the .py file and then when i start the React app i am able to fetch the data . But how to start (localhost:5000/data) on clicking the button ??

Comment: sorry, the question is not clear ... What do you mean by "start" ?

Comment: There should be data in json format at ( http://localhost:5000/data ) right after i clicked on button . I got some ideas about using ajax but i am not getting it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a bit of a misunderstanding of how an API work, first you should jsonify your data so wrap your return with jsonify.

```
return jsonify({'name': "geek", "password": "This is PWD"})
```

Then before doing anything fancy, access your endpoint at /data and see if any data is there... There should be or check your code.

If everything works, then try:

```
   fetch('http://localhost:5000/data')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

It should return some data.

Before jumping into React, you should understand the API and the fetch library.

Comment: Above code works fine but only when the .py file is already running on the server . But i don't want it to run that file manually . It should run after button click from app.js file . But when i run only react app alone It says [GET http://localhost:5000/data net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED]. What i want is how to run .py file on button click from App.js file in React application . Both the files are on the same users computer .

Comment: what is the use case I don't understand and it seems like it's not the way it works tmk

Comment: I want to create a user only after i click the button and then i want to fetch the account username and password .

Comment: Yes, ok but we cannot provide the code unless you do the work first, build something in the backend with some database, user management etc... Also you obviously do not understand flask, api and how a server work on your local machine, why would jump on using React ?

Comment: And of course it works when the server is running, but in the real world you backend would run 24/7, but this is for development only it runs on your machine

Comment: Yes , it works when the server is running and for development purpose it is running on my local machine .